# Round of to lowest value

Tags: plsql

The following statement below does the rounding of the value to the next number, The above answer is actually 3,5. How do I round of the current value to 3 instead of 4.

```
l_low number := 1;
l_high number := 7;

l_mid := trunc(l_low + (l_high - l_low)/2);
```

Comment: Why do you think the answer should be 3? `(7 - 1) / 2 = 3` and `trunc(3 + 1) = trunc(4) = 4`

Comment: apart from the calculation, if it's your purpose to round down always, you want to use
   floor( 7/2)

Comment: @NonPlusUltra `FLOOR` and `TRUNC` are synonymous when you're working with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is almost correct, but the `(` and `)` are not completly correct. 
 Think this is what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE
        l_low NUMBER := 1;
        l_high NUMBER := 7;

        l_mid NUMBER;
BEGIN
        l_mid := TRUNC((l_low + (l_high - l_low)) / 2);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_mid);
END;
/
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `(l_low + (l_high - l_low))` could be simplified to just `l_high`. In other words, this ignores the value of `l_low` which certainly doesn't give the "mid point" if that's what the purpose is. e.g. if `l_low = 5` and `l_high = 6` this results in `3` which is outside the bounds.